# PyOpenGL glGenTextures returns 0

Tags: python, opengl, textures, pyopengl

I am using pyopengl with pygame, and I want to display an image on a quad. Every time I have used `glGenTextures(1,img)` it returns 0. I have read about needing to call this function in a context but I don't know how to set one up.

Here is my code up untill using glGenTexures:

```
import pygame, OpenGL, math, numpy
from pygame.locals import *
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
from PIL import Image #have Pillow instead of PIL

img = Image.open('myPixelArt2.bmp')
glGenTextures(1,img)

print glGenTextures(1,img)
print img
```

Which prints out

```
0
<PIL.BmpImagePlugin.BmpImageFile image mode=RGB size=64x64 at 0x3A4E9B8>
```

How do I get glGenTextures to return 1?
I have tried calling glGenTexures(1), and have tried a jpg image, but neither changes anything.

Answer (score 0):

> I have read about needing to call this function in a context but I
>   don't know how to set one up.

But that is the key point here. You can't use OepnGL without an OpenGL context. Usually, there are some platform-specific APIs wich allow you to create and manage GL contexts and to "connect" them to windows so that you can actually get anything visible to the screen with GL.

Oftentimes, one does not use these low-level, platform-specic APIs, but some higher-level abstractions which internally deal with all those platform-specific details. Since you use python and PyGame, you probably want to use [PyOpenGL](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/), which can create contexts for you. But OpenGL is a complex topic, learning it will reuire lots of effort.

Comment: Thankyou, I have now installed OpenGLContext, (and PyVRML97 and PyDispatcher) but how do I activate a context? Do I call anything in particular in my script before glGenTextures? I have imported OpenGLContext.textures at the top of my script - does this activate a context by itself?

Comment: @MattMaich: hmm, that namig is unfortunate. PyOpenGL's OpenGLContext is not directly about OpenGL contexts. But it is some sort of simple scenegraph library. I wasn't aware of that thing before... But that OpenGLContext thing provides different GL context creation mechanisms: via glut, via wxwindows and via pygame itself

Answer (score 0):

I don't know PyOpenGL, think of creating a context as starting up the OpenGL engine.  You can see here for how to create a context:

http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/context/tutorials/shader_1.html
(uses pyopengl's [OpenGLContext](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/context/))

`glGenTextures` asks the system to return integer which can be used as a texture ID. The first parameter is the number of texture ID integers you want, and it returns that many IDs.

There is pyopengl translation of a NeHe tutorial about texture mapping here: http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/context/tutorials/nehe6.html